# ¿cómo validar fecha de mi formulario no sea anterior a la del sistema?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un calendar por un Date Picker y necesito que me valide que la fecha ingresada no sea menor a la del sistema. Para eso estoy pensando guardar en dos variables la fecha del sistema y la que ingreso y luego compararlos. Y cuál sería la mejor opción (javascritp ó jquery) Mas o menos mi lógica es como se muestra. Me ayudan please.

```
var = fech_ingr;
var = fech_sistema;
$(document).ready(function () {

   if (fech_ingr<fech_sistema){

        return 
   }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

En las opciones de inciacion del datePicker pon:

```
minDate:<fecha_del_sistema>
```

o una vez iniciado:

```
$('#datepickerId').datepicker('option',{minDate:new Date()}).datepicker('refresh');
```

Comment: y como capturaría la fecha del sistema?

Comment: un ejemplo que tengas por ahi¡¡¡¡

Comment: La fecha del sistema la coje la funcion "new Date()" se la pasa en milisegundos al datepicker, puedes ver la documentacion aqui https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: Si lo inicias desde php la fecha del sistema es la funcion time()